# Tor Browser not suggesting ".onion available"?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I am using Tor Browser 11.5.7 (based on Mozilla Firefox 91.13.0esr) (64-bit)

[torproject support](https://support.torproject.org/onionservices/onion-location/) says:

> Onion-Location is a new HTTP header that web sites can use to
> advertise their onion counterpart. If the web site that you're
> visiting has an onion site available, a purple suggestion pill will
> prompt at the URL bar saying ".onion available". When you click on
> ".onion available", the web site will be reloaded and redirected to
> its onion counterpart.

Earlier, when I browsed a site (in Tor Browser) which has a .onion counterpart, the browser would suggest ".onion available". Now it is not doing that. What might be the reason? How can I get the early behavior?

Comment: I think it's might be because they use two different servers to their onion and clearnet address.

Comment: The most likely reason is like you just described - if a .onion site is available then the website operators have to **advertise** it proactively, by sending those headers. Most likely they aren't, and this is something you could easily check, either by looking at the HTML source code, or watching the **response headers** using the browser tools.